# VB.NET Events aren't working or displaying info?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am currently attempting to query my database to link it to my login screen. 
So when you enter a password for the login to say "invalid user" etc.

But, I go to set the button_click function, and in the Events, I could not find `button1`, only found page load, even though I right clicked and went to properties on the button. It only displayed a blank drop down and something called PageLoad. Can anyone help with this issue?

Snippet:

```
 <p class="submitButton">
                    <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" 
                        ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" onclick="Page_Load"/>
                </p>

Public Class Login

    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register.aspx?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"))

    End Sub



End Class
```

[See image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkJSA.png)

Comment: That's all you see in the drop-down because that's all you've got in the code-behind.  If you want to generate a new event handler then clear the selection in the drop-down and then double-click the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **onclick="Page_Load"** ,

Try to add a click handler manually like this

```
Protected Sub button1_Click(sender as Object, e as System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click

End Sub
```